# Redefining subsubsection

Tags: macros, sectioning

In book class, subsubsections induce huge spacing before and after and makes the structure too empty for my taste. Hence I would like to redefine it in order to get the one present in amsart for instance (spacing before if necessary, boldface in standard font size, followed with a dot and a space).

How can I do so?

Comment: You should take a look at package `titlesec`.

Comment: you could take a look into how it's defined in `amsart` and copy that definition into your preamble, wrapped between `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`.